# transformer - how to call a module with variables as default value?

Tags: variables, terraform, terraform-template-file

I created a simple module with some variables, for example:
Inside modules->network folder->main.tf:

```
(...)
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}
```

Inside the same folder, variables.tf :

```
variable "aws_region" {
  type        = string
  default     = "us-east-1"
}
(...)
```

Now when I call this module inside setup -> main.tf:

```
module "Network" {
  source = "../modules/Network"
  aws_region = ?
(...)
}
```

What can I put in the " aws_region = " to make it get the original default value of this variable?
I know I can hard-code it or add another variables.tf file to the setups folder, but this is not  good solution as I will need to maintain every variable in 2 locations..

Thx.

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using? You shouldn't have to define the provider at the module level in newer versions, unless the configuration requires aliased providers IIRC.

Comment: Also, you might as well leave out the `aws_region` from the module call and it should work.

Comment: Hey, actually I just figure this out - if you give it a default value in the module variable, there is no need to declare it at all under the module..

Comment: Not only should you not have to define a provider in a module, but if you do it is completely ignored https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers

Comment: This is the default behavior. If you pass the default, there is no need to pass anything in the calling module block. It will automatically use the default. That's what they are meant for.

Answer (score 4):

The main way that Terraform uses default values for variables is if you omit the argument entirely when you call the module. The presence of a `default` argument is what makes the argument optional:

```
module "network" {
  source = "../modules/network"
}
```

---

There is one additional way you can make use of default values: if you change the declaration of the variable to include [`nullable = false`](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#disallowing-null-input-values) then Terraform will treat an explicit `null` value the same as omitting the argument entirely.

Here's the updated declaration:

```
variable "aws_region" {
  type     = string
  default  = "us-east-1"
  nullable = false
}
```

And then when you call the module, you can assign `null`:

```
module "network" {
  source = "../modules/network"

  aws_region = null
}
```

By default, without `nullable = false`, Terraform would literally set `var.aws_region` to `null`, but with this extra setting we tell Terraform to use the default value instead in that case.

Setting it directly to `null` is not very useful since it's the same as omitting it entirely, but this extra behavior can be useful if you need to *sometimes* set the argument:

```
# Note: this is a different var.aws_region in the root
# module, _not_ the one inside the network module.
variable "aws_region" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

module "network" {
  source = "../modules/network"

  aws_region = var.aws_region
}
```

Notice that now there's an input variable `aws_region` in the calling module too, but this one has `default = null` which means that leaving it unset will cause it to be `null`. I then passed that through to `module "network"` directly, and because the module's own `variable "aws_region"` has `nullable = false` a null value would get automatically replaced with the default, without having to duplicate the default value in the calling module's declaration.

Answer (score 1):

actually I just figure this out - if you give it a default value in the module variable.tf file, there is no need to declare it at all under setups->main.tf. you can just write

```
module "Network" {
  source = "../modules/Network"
}
```

And it will take all the default value for variables not called here